# JSON Query Parameters Not Working - RESTful API

Tags: json

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "local_alias": [
    {
      "8188": {
        "result": {
          "status": "success",
          "location": "Europe",
          "primary_overflow_location": "Europe",
          "secondary_overflow_location": "USA"
        }
      },
      "8988": {
        "result": {
          "status": "success",
          "location": "USA",
          "primary_overflow_location": "USA",
          "secondary_overflow_location": "Europe"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can browse to the resource just fine, but when I add a query parameter to it, it returns everything.

```
$resource/?local_alias=8988
```

How do I get it so that it returns my search correctly?

Comment: You need a script to get the query parameter, then parse the json with something like JSON.parse for JS or json_decode() for PHP and then match the query parameter to the key (in this case) 8988

Comment: I'm using NPM json-server for this.  Can you point me off in the right direction where I can learn more on how to set this up?  Everything I'm running into is resulting in massive errors.  Who would have thought something (I presume to be simple) could be so annoyingly complex...